# Rails Post Date Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I am attempting to build a Rails blog and I am currently in the final stages. I’ve managed to work around and develop most if not all features of a Wordpress blog, but one which is currently blocking me is being able to have an ‘archive’ of blogs. 
I know how to display a post by it’s date time and/or sort posts which were created at a specific time, but i’m unsure how to have a page with a month and year and display those posts.

For example 
I’ve uploaded a post in July 2014, how could I automatically have rails create a new page with parameters called `/july-2014` which would then automatically display `Posts where created_at == july 2014`.

The creation of a new parameter with a set field is my main problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a catch-all route for routes like `/july-2014` to work, so put this at the bottom of your routes file:

```
get '/:month_name', to: 'posts#index'
```

The string `July-2014` should actually be parseable as is, so give this a try:

```
Class PostController < ApplicationController
  def index
    date = Date.parse(params[:month_name])
    @posts = Post.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", date.beginning_of_month, date.end_of_month)
  end
end
```

This example is the bare minimum, you'll probably want to guard against invalid dates and missing month_name param

Comment: This line `date = Date.parse(params[:monthyear])` is causing an unhelpful error `no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Comment: It probably means that `params[:monthyear]` is nil. Did you add the route and change `:month_name` to  `:monthyear` there as well?

Comment: `monthyear` is a date time field which was once a string but that i changed to date time (should I change back to string), and Yes I did change month_name to monthyear in the routes

Comment: I've added a new string column called `month_name` and have implemented your code in controller and routes but I am still getting `no implicit conversion of nil into String`